# How to find the smallest prime divisors of $2^{19}-1$ and $2^{37}-1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, soft-question

How to find the smallest prime divisors of  $2^{19}-1$ and $2^{37}-1$ ?

I'm new to elementary number theory and I'm not sure what to do AT ALL.
We're currently studying primitive roots and indices.

Comment: You didn't even give your question 10 minutes, and this website is for both professionals, amateurs, enthusiasts, or grandmas. Mainly it's full of people who enjoy taking time to help others, so please have some patience.

Comment: What tools are you allowed?  $2^{19}-1=524287$, as shown by [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+2%5E19-1).  That is small enough that trial division only has to go to $724$.  Do you have a list of primes at hand?  You will find a factor of $2^{37}-1$ even faster.

Comment: It looks like Fermat's Little Theorem could be useful.

Comment: How could I encorporate Fermat's theorem?

Comment: And the only knowledge that we're given is that "All primes will have the form 2kp+1"

Comment: What is $p$ in your $2 k p + 1$?

Comment: 19 and 37 :P :P :P :P :P

Comment: Fermat theorem will just prove $2^{37}-1$ is not prime, it won't prove $2^{19}-1$ *is* prime (which it is). But since it's so small, trial division is enough, especially if you know prime factors have the form $38k+1$ (only 20 divisions or so to check).

Comment: This is *not* a site for professionals. This is a site *for all* levels and fields in mathematics. A site that is more leaned towards professional mathematics is the **Math Overflow (MO)**. You can visit there, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

As for $2^{19}-1$, one can perform one of the [Primality tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test). This is immediately succesful and the result is that $2^{19}-1$ is the smallest prime divisor of $2^{19}-1$.
Details can be found by looking for so-called *Mersenne prime numbers*. For example, see the [Lucas test](http://primes.utm.edu/mersenne/LukeMirror/lit/lit_007s.htm).
For $2^{37}-1$, the trial and error method is successful. Just divide this odd number by all small primes $3,5,7,\ldots ,223$.

Answer (score 0):

Smallest prime divisor of  $2^{19}-1$

Let's consider any general prime to be p.

If it's a divisor -

$2^{19}-1=0(mod  p)$

$2^{19}=1(mod  p)$

therefore $19|(p-1)$

As $p>3$

$2|(p-1)$

general prime divisors are $(p-1)=2*19*k$
                                          $p=(38*k+1)$

Similarily for $2^{37}-1$

$p=(74*k+1)$